# No Roo installation configured in workspace preferences

Tags: spring-roo

Downloaded latest eclipse (indigo 3.7) and the latest sts (SpringSourceTool 2.9.1.RELEASE) plugin.
I'm trying my luck with my first Roo project but when tryin to create the project getting:

No Roo installation configured in workspace preferences.

According to the manuals sts is all I need.
Have I missed something here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try preferences, type "Roo" in the search field in order to find the Roo configuration option, and if it exists, you can choose the Roo installation path(s) from there.

Previously, you have to download and install Roo.

Alternatively, you can install the SpringSource Tool Suite directly, that comes with Eclipse, a couple of useful plugins, and with three programs: maven, Roo and VMWare TC server (a customized tomcat server)

Comment: Ok, so I have installed the SpringSource Tool Suite directly, that comes with Eclipse (from the Eclipse market-place). Where can I find my roo installation dir now? Or should I install roo separately in addition to the plugin?